# replace all occurrence of special character using regexp_replace

Tags: sql, postgresql

I work with postgresql 11

I want to replace all occurrence of `|` **and only the first character after `|`** in my string

```
"|aDerivatives :|bprinciples and practice /|cRangarajan K. Sundaram, |fSanjiv R. Das."
```

meaning in my example replace `|a` and `|b` and `|c` and `|f`  with ''

I try with this code but it replace only `|a`

```
select regexp_replace('|aDerivatives :|bprinciples and practice /|cRangarajan K. Sundaram, |fSanjiv R. Das.', '\|[A-Za-z]','')
```

the output is :

```
"Derivatives :|bprinciples and practice /|cRangarajan K. Sundaram, |fSanjiv R. Das."
```

the correct output should be :

```
"Derivatives :principles and practice /Rangarajan K. Sundaram, Sanjiv R. Das."
```

can someone help me to find the correct query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
  regexp_replace(
   '"|aDerivatives :|bprinciples and practice /|cRangarajan K. Sundaram, |fSanjiv R. Das."',
   '\|[A-Za-z]',
   '',
   'g');
                                 regexp_replace                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 "Derivatives :principles and practice /Rangarajan K. Sundaram, Sanjiv R. Das."
(1 row)
```

- `g` ("global") flag to replace multiple occurrences of a pattern